# .NET bind checked property of checkbox with SqlByte datatype

Tags: c#, types, bindingsource

This fails:

```
dtaAutomaticFlag.DataBindings.Add("Checked", BndSource, "AutomaticFlag");
```

most probably because AutomaticFlag is defined as:

```
public SqlByte AutomaticFlag { get; set; }
```

SQL Server is tinyint. The reason is that i dont only need 0 and 0 as values.

I need to be checked if the value is 1 , unchecked for ALL other values.

One thing that i thought is to create an extra property AutomaticFlagBoolean in my class and check the AutomaticFlag and bind to the new property.

**This is what i tried but i get always false:**

```
    private SqlByte _automaticFlag;
    public SqlByte AutomaticFlag
    {
        get { return _automaticFlag; }
        set
        {
            if (_automaticFlagBoolean)
            {
                _automaticFlag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                _automaticFlag = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _automaticFlagBoolean;
    public bool AutomaticFlagBoolean
    {
        get
        {
            if (_automaticFlag == 1)
            {
                return _automaticFlagBoolean = true;
            }
            else
            {
                return _automaticFlagBoolean = false;
            }
        }
        set { _automaticFlagBoolean = value; }
    }
```

this is in my binding:

```
dtaAutomaticFlag.DataBindings.Add("Checked", BndSource, "AutomaticFlagBoolean");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox control expects a boolean value for binding.

Try using a local variable to hold the value:

```
private SqlByte _automaticFlag;
private bool _automaticFlagBoolean;

public SqlByte AutomaticFlag
{
    get { return _automaticFlag; }
    set
    {
        _automaticFlag = value;
        _automaticFlagBoolean = (_automaticFlag != 0);
    }
}

public bool AutomaticFlagBoolean
{
    get
    {
        return _AutomaticFlagBookean;
    }
    set { _automaticFlagBoolean = value; 
       if (_automaticFlagBoolean) {
          _automaticFlag = 1;
       } else {
          _automaticFlag = 0;
       }
    }
}
```

Then bind as so:

```
dtaAutomaticFlag.DataBindings.Add("Checked", BndSource, "AutomaticFlagBoolean");
```

Your class should also implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) as well but that's a little beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: and what i will bind to my dtaAutomaticFlag.DataBindings.Add?

Comment: I updated my question with what i tried with your suggestion but it doesnt work. I get always false value

Comment: @e4rthdog: I updated my answer. You have some concerning design issues here, but my answer should prevent the recursion and should allow you to bind the boolean to a checkbox (although without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, any changes in code to your property will not reflect to the bound control.)

Comment: i saw my flaws and i reverted in doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692566/binding-to-checked-propert-messes-up-ui-binding-to-text-is-fine i would appreciate if you gave a look there also...

Comment: Would you also care to explain to tme exaclty your design concerns?