# Binding to checked propert messes up ui, binding to text is fine

Tags: c#, checkbox, bind, bindingsource

**UPDATE:**

I think i have found the problem.

All my forms events that affect the binding source have this in the end:

```
BndSource.ResetBindings(false);
```

If i comment this line in my CheckedChanged event handler, the issue stops. But why?

I have a very strange bug.

I have a class property:

```
public SqlByte AutomaticFlag { get; set; }
```

I wanted to use checkbox to facilitate for showing this so in initial inding i do this:

```
        dtaAutomaticFlag.DataBindings.Add("Checked", BndSource, "AutomaticFlag", true);
        dtaAutomaticFlag.DataBindings[0].Format += (s, e) =>
        {
            if ((SqlByte)e.Value == 1)
            {
                e.Value = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Value = false;
            }
        };
```

the problem is that during iteration through all records of the binding source my ui is half updated, meaning its not complete. See picture:

[image]

VERY strangely when i change the above binding property from checked to text like this:

```
dtaAutomaticFlag.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSource, "AutomaticFlag", true);
```

the ui is ok!!

Picture:

[image]

Comment: Updated the question in the first 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to this particular situation. But rather than adding the binding as you did:

```
dtaAutomaticFlag.DataBindings.Add("Text", BndSource, "AutomaticFlag", true);
```

Does creating a "new" binding instance help at all?

```
dtaAutomaticFlag.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", BndSource, "AutomaticFlag", true));
```

Comment: Have a look at this post.  This seems to be related to your issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651702/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-datagridview-to-fire-its-cellformatting-event-for-all

Comment: I think i have found what causes the problem. I will update the question